# In Go, of what type is a file when I'm using fmt.Printf?

Tags: go

I'm using `fmt.Fprintf(file, "<string>")`, but in a function. I create the new file using `xmlFile :=` in the main function and then pass that variable to the call of a function that writes to the file, but I am getting an error for the file parametre that it doesn't have a type. What type should I give it?

It is not a string, it is a file.

Of what type is a file?

Here is what the definition of the function looks like:

```
func processTopic(id string, properties map[string][]string, file){
```

Comment: can you please show the right part of `xmlFile := ` expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fprintf):

```
func Fprintf(w io.Writer, format string, a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)
```

Fprintf accepts an `io.Writer`. `io.Writer` is an interface which means that you an pass any type that implements it. This includes `*os.File` (system file) and `*bytes.Buffer` (memory).